# MySQL Stored Procedure DELETEs all Rows instead of just one

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying out stored procedures for the first time, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `answers` (
  `anid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dtid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `answer` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`anid`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `dtid` (`dtid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

`anid` is the primary key, `uid` is user id, `dtid` is datum id, and `answer` is the answer provided.
Whenever I get a new answer for a given datum (question) and user id, I want to first delete any old answer to that same question by that same user, and then insert the new one.

Here's the procedure declaration:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE new_answer(uid INT(11),dtid INT(11),answer TEXT)
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM `answers` WHERE `uid` = uid AND `dtid` = dtid;
    INSERT INTO `answers` SET `uid` = uid, `dtid` = dtid, `answer` = answer;
END//
```

However, whenever I `CALL` `new_answer` ALL existing rows are deleted, and that one new answer is now the only row in the table.
Hope it's something simple, thanks for your help.

Comment: WHERE `uid` = uid and `dtid` = dtid is always true...

Comment: @Konerak Indeed. I had _imagined_ the backticks would have them tokenized as column names and not procedure parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably try naming procedure arguments different than table columns.

Anyway, it looks like all you need is a single `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query.

Comment: Would `ON DUPLICATE KEY` work, even though neither `uid` nor `dtid` are primary key?

Comment: Add a UNIQUE key on (uid, dtid) then.

Comment: Fantastic, I'm giving you the answer for teaching my something new. (I didn't know you could do multi-column keys)
Also ty @Konerak

Comment: Definitely read this then: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-column-indexes.html as there are some important things to know about compund indexes. Actually entire 7.3 section is interesting.

Answer (score 4):

Rename your parameters:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE new_answer(p_uid INT(11),p_dtid INT(11),p_answer TEXT)
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM `answers` WHERE `uid` = p_uid AND `dtid` = p_dtid;
    INSERT INTO `answers` SET `uid` = p_uid, `dtid` = p_dtid, `answer` = p_answer;
END//
```

Comment: this worked, thanks! I thought adding the backticks would be clear enough, i guess it wasn't =)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with stored procedures, but what about renaming your function parameters to x and y instead of the very same as the column names?

Comment: yeah, that did it (as yankee also suggested). I had thought backticks would be sufficient the differentiate vars from actual columns. Thanks

Comment: Anyway, it's an interesting issue: at any other point of the procedure, there's no problem with it. There are no fixed set of "reserved" words for parameters and variables, it occurs problem only in case when you use a table wich includes a conflicting column name.